invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /var/run/docker.sock
I am running rootless docker. And trying to spawn a devcontainer with docker-outside-docker feature. When I try to run the container, I get an error
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /var/run/docker.sock.

This path doesn't exist on my system as it is rootless I think and the actual path will be unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock.
Is this a bug in the Feature or I should be doing something to fix it in my system.
{
    "name": "MyApi",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/dotnet:1-8.0-bookworm",
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-outside-of-docker:1": {},
    },
    "forwardPorts": [50111, 50111],
    "portsAttributes": {
            "50111": {
                "protocol": "https"
            }
    }
}


